# jquery loop for div

Tags: jquery, loops

I have the following code in repeat.

```
<div class="background1"></div>

 <i class="fa fa-share" alt="share"  title="Share"></i>
 <div class="large1">
      <div class="ttip">
          <div>Here goes contents...</div>
              <span class="note">(click here to close the box)</span>
      </div>
 </div>
```

I want to display the div with class large1 and the background. This is the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/rjGeS/83/) (not mine. found it on net) in repeat.

I tried to do the following in java-script

```
$('.fa-share').click(function (){
                    $(this).next(".large1").first().html(function() {
                                $(this).prev(".background1").css({"opacity": "0.3"}).fadeIn("slow");
                                $(this).next('.ttip').css({left: $(this).position() + '20px',top: $(this).position() + '50px'}).show(500)
                    }).fadeIn("slow");

                    $(this).next('.note').on('click', function() {
                        $(this).prev('.ttip').hide(500);
                        $(this).prev(".background1").fadeOut("slow");
                        $(this).prev(".large1").fadeOut("slow");
                    });
                });
```

I had tried using ".each()" on first click but did not work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.large1` is not a child of your `i` - instead of `find` try `.next(".large1")`

Comment: `.next` searches for siblings right? But in my case those are not siblings.

Comment: looks like siblings to me in your example

Comment: Also `$(this).closest(".background1")` won't work. `.background1` should be a parent for `$(this)` element.

Comment: anyway i tried that but did not work.

Comment: first of all: `i` don't has any children..

Comment: @W92 so how should i go about it?

Comment: reading the API will help you a lot with these issues.. http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ - You have to be able to know what you're trying to do.  `$(this).find(".large1")` - you have no children of element with class `.fa-share` - `$(this).closest(".background1")` - `.large1` has no ancestor element with class `.background` - theres either a lot of elements out of place or a lot of work you need to do with your selectors

Comment: @maddog wait a moment, i'm trying to resolve your problem. max 5 min and you will have the solution.

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ ok. will change the code. i got confused with `.find` and `.closest`. Its been long time since i played with jQuery so very rusty. sorry folks.

Comment: Ok. Now i changed the `.closest` to `.prev` and `.find` to `.next` with no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVM
I got it working. 
Thanks all of you.

```
$('.fa-share').click(function (){
                        $(this).prev(".background1").css({"opacity": "0.3"}).fadeIn("slow");
                        $(this).next(".large1").html(function() {$('.ttip').css({left: $(this).position() + '20px',top: $(this).position() + '50px'}).show(500)
                        }).fadeIn("slow");
                    });
                $('.note').on('click', function() {
                    $(this).closest('.ttip').hide(500);
                    $$(this).closest(".large1").prev(".fa-share").prev(".background1").fadeOut("slow");
                    $(this).closest(".large1").fadeOut("slow");
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

it may help you:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.fa-share').on('click', 'a.note', function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.large1').fadeIn();
            $('.background1').fadeIn();
        });

        $('.large1').on('click', 'span.note', function () {
            $(this).closest('.large1').fadeOut();
            $('.background1').fadeOut();
        });
    });

<div class="background1" style="display:none;">
    <p>here's some text</p>
</div>

<i class="fa fa-share" alt="share" title="Share">
    <a href="#" class="note">click to show large1 and background1</a>
</i>
<div class="large1" style="display:none;">
    <div class="ttip">
        <div>Here goes contents...</div>
        <span class="note">(click here to close the box)</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S
I think that you don't have any base knowledge about jquery and javascript. I'm suggesting you that look at this page:
https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-jquery and learn with this course. It will give you a lot knowledge about basic level for js/jquery.
(If the upper link will don't work search on google: codeschool tryjquery course free basic level 1)